# How I can let my program stop taking any mouse Click while function paintComponent running?

Tags: java, swing

I want my program stop taking any function mouse Click until function paintComponent done ,

I have jlabel and it has function mouseClick  , when the user click  the label start paintComponent but i don't want the user click again while the function paintComponent working ,  function paintComponent takes one seconde , while this one second I want all labels stop taking any click .

I cant use (sleep) because its let all program stop .

function paintComponent in class and function mouseClick in another class

How I can do that ????

I hope understand my issue ...

Comment: Try to put some code?

Comment: Firstly a paintComponent method should never take long to run, and certainly never one second, but rather it needs to be lightning fast. Hopefully you're not trying to read in images or any other external resources from within that method. Next of all, to pause all mouse input, you could use a boolean in your mouse listener that actives/deactivates the listener. e.g., in the mousePressed method, place all the code within a `if (mouseListenerActive) {...}` block, and then toggle the state of the mouseListenerActive boolean.

Comment: can you write sample code for that please ??

Comment: I'd be happy to try to work with your code, so please post what you've got, preferably a [mcve], and never in a link -- post all code here as an edit to your question.

Comment: its work good now , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though you have a fair amount of processing required to repaint the component. If that is done on the event dispatch thread then your UI will become unresponsive while the painting occurs. That's not what you want.

A possible solution is to use a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) object. You can kick off the processing and even display output as it proceeds.

Ideally you want to give some visual indication to the user that input is disabled while this processing occurs. This means that you should use `setEnable(false)` on components that are no longer active (and `setEnable(true)` in `SwingWorker.done()`). However this will be ignored by your `MouseListener` (see [`setEnabled`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setEnabled-boolean-). So you will also need to check whether the component is enabled inside your processing code. You can use `isEnabled()` on the relevant component or have a separate boolean flag.

Here's some sample code to give you an idea of what I mean:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Click Me To Load Image");
label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        if (label.isEnabled()) {
            loadImage();
        }
    }
}

void loadImage() {
    SwingWorker<Image, Object> imageLoader= new SwingWorker<>() {
        public Image doInBackground() {
            // do long task and return result
        }
        public void done() {
            imageToPaint = get();
            repaint();
            label.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    label.setEnabled(false);
    imageLoader.execute();
}
```

Comment: bunch of events from `repaint();` isn't sets to concrete `JComponent`, this isn't necessary, have to call `(Image)Icon.flush()` before is added to `JLabel`, +1 for a) SwingWorker, b) EDT